# ASP.net MVC 3 Razor - jQuery Intellisense

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, intellisense, razor

I am using Visual Studio 2010 / ASP.net MVC 3 with the Razor View Engine. I created a new Project with the Internet Application template. What do I need to do to get Intellisense working?

Comment: Isn't it working right now? Maybe try reinstalling ASP.NET MVC 3.

Comment: It is not. I just installed it a few days ago. :(

Comment: Maybe open a bug at Microsoft Connect site. I see that many people are complaining about this. This being said, I've never had problems with it :-) Not that I care much about Intellisense but it could come handy at times.

Comment: this topic helped me a lot more (vs 2012 users): 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488208/intellisense-doesnt-work-for-js-in-vs2012

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If that's jQuery specific as the title specifies, trying adding  line to the  tag in the `Views/Shared/_layout.cshtml` (or `.vbhtml`) file:

```
@if (false) { <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script> }
```

This will reference the intellisense file to VisualStudio and still will not reference it in runtime.

Just remember, point to the vsdoc file relatively to the file you put this code in. Any code like `~`/`Url.Content()` or any other runtime code will not be visible to VS for intellisense.
That's exactly why `if (false)` hides the script reference from runtime (the `if` block isn't executed), but doesn't hide it from VS intellisense (and provide another reference using `Url.Content()` or so to the .min.js file).

Comment: That didn't work either unfortunately. Might need to reinstall VS2010 or something.

Comment: Do you have Resharper installed? If so, which version? and Does changing intellisene option in R# settings to Visual Studio change anything?

Comment: You can use the same trick in *.js files. Drag and drop from the solution explorer. I didn't realize this at first, hope it helps.

Comment: @MohamedMeligy: That works for me. Along with the comment about not using `@Url.Content(...)` on Greg's answer. What I do not understand is, what is the meaning of `if(false){...}` That seems to be pointless but it works!! Can you explain?

Comment: The `if(false) {...}` bit is to prevent the code from executing in runtime, so that the large heavily commented -vsdoc.js is not referenced in runtime (you are expected to have a separate reference to the min.js file as well to be executed and referenced as you do normally). Using `Url.Content()`/`~` or any code that's evaluated in runtime will prevent VS from detecting the -vsdoc.js file for intellisense. I've added these notes to the answer itself. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Additionally to add the `intellisense.js` file I needed to add the jQuery file too.

Answer (score 9):

From http://blog.meidianto.com/2010/05/13/vs2010-tips-7-how-to-make-jquery-intellisense-work-for-external-javascript-file/

Drag the jquery file into the js file you want intellisense on like this:
[image]

Then it will work like this:
[image]

Comment: The question is about Razor files (.cshtml, .vbthml) not JavaScript files. The `<reference>` syntax works when you need automcomplete from one JavaScript file in another JavaScript file (.js).

Comment: I am also facing same problem, Tried your drag and drop referencing. Now it is working, But in this way I have to drag and drop jquery*.js file in all my views. 

Is there a way so that I will reference in Layout view and it will automatically come in all views

Answer (score 4):

I found good explanation which worked for me at:
http://theycallmemrjames.blogspot.com/2011/03/jquery-intellisense-with-aspnet-mvc-and.html

These lines:

```
 @if (false) 
{ 
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
}
```

should be added to every view (where intellisense is needed). This will enable intellisense but will not add the second reference at runtime.

Comment: I have found that intellisense does not work when you use Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js") in your script references. Apparently it can't determine the path until you run. YOu also seem to need to do this in every single page you want intellisense in, not just adding it to the layout/master.

Comment: Wow, so basically the intellisense is completely useless unless you clutter EVERY view with useless if blocks for EACH javascript reference you want intellisense for.  Really disappointed in Visual Studio right now.

Comment: @John Bubriski see my ans below.

Answer (score 2):

Seems for me in Vs2012 with a _layout.cshtml that the solution from @Mohamed Meligy doesn't help in views using that layout file. Maybe I'm missing something?

However - the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319726/661584) which **seems to be recommended approach seems to work a treat** and now I have intellisense for all references to all files I add references to in _references.js and don't need the runtime false trick bit, and can keep the views totally clean of references.