# What is the _references.js used for?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the _references.js file used for in a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project?

Answer (score 268, accepted):

> In VS 11, Visual Studio will give you intellisense from all files
> that have references in the “_references.js” file.

[For More Info](http://gurustop.net/blog/2012/03/03/javascript-js-intellisense-auto_complete-in-visual-studio-11-beta-the-web-_references-js-file/) ([Web Archive backup link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210411000910/http://gurustop.net/blog/2012/03/03/javascript-js-intellisense-auto_complete-in-visual-studio-11-beta-the-web-_references-js-file/))

Comment: I didn't even appreciate why I was getting angular intellisense. <3 Visual Studio!

Comment: Yes, but where is "_references.js" referenced from?

Answer (score 23):

MSDN documentation: [JavaScript IntelliSense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx)

In brief, _references.js stores the list of JS files paths, for which you want the Visual Studio to gather and build the intelisense (aka "code complete"). The VS project adds there some common JS libraries like jQuery to build the intellisense for it. You can add a reference to your custom JS file in form like this:

```
/// <reference path="MyScriptFile.js" />
```

Comment: In my experience, usage by Visual Studio (2017) has grown beyond just intellisense.  I found that if, for example, `jquery-2.2.2.min.js` was not mentioned in `_references.js`, then it wouldn't get deployed and there would be a run time failure using jquery.

Comment: ...this may be some kind of interaction with TypeScript and VS's bundler.

Answer (score 12):

From Visual Studio 2017 forward, this file is [no longer used.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/javascript-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#notable-changes-from-visual-studio-2015)