# Visual Studio MVC wont load some javascript files

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, visual-studio-2012

I just started a new project `File > ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application > Internet Application`

The problem i have is when I run the project it throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'splitter'`  I know what the error means but the plugin file for the SPLITTER is loaded correctly.

I then started the project in a folder without the aid of Visual Studio - same file stucture,  same code, everything works as expected.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="splitter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
             $(".panel").splitter();
         });

     </script>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: @Cybermaxs-Betclic Its not a 404, on **Visual Studio** it can't find the method within splitter.js

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't load anything.  Your browser does.  The difference is that Visual Studio starts the browser in a debugging mode, which the browser is not doing when you start it without it.  The error still occurs, you just don't see it.  Check the JavaScript console to see.

Comment: @MystereMan CONSOLE? MMM WOW HOW COME I DIDN'T THINK OF THAT - Einstein! :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the issue was `$().ready(function () {...` when working with a couple of jQuery plugins some use `$` as something else (i.e: variable or instance of something) now when It gets to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
        $(".panel").splitter();
    });
</script>
```

somehow `$` is not at its native jQuery state. So to make sure I use it as I know it (the native jQuery way) It has to be passed to the function, like so...

`jQuery(function ($) {...`

So Visual Studio was not the issue :)

(My terminology is a bit rusty, feel free to edit so it can make sense)

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to call all your script in your "_Layout.cshtml" under the Folder Shared and add your scripts to Folder "Scripts"

then say somethink like that in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/splitter.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

so in all your views the script is loaded and should be correct loaded! 
**UPDATE:**
in your view try :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".panel").splitter();
    window.splitter();         <------ try
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IF the error is in Visual Studio, you need to add the splitter.js file to the _references.js file. This is how VS knows which Js files to check.

[What is the _references.js used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319645/what-is-the-references-js-used-for)