# Is It Possible to Dynamically Generate JavaScript Reference Directives?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I'm working on a team of developers that keeps reference directives in various files for intellisense purposes. As you can imagine, it's impossible to maintain these files. As such, I'd like to know if there's a way to dynamically generate them. Any way. At all. No matter how kooky.

Here's a reference to the kind of thing I'm talking about: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb385682.aspx#ReferenceDirectives

I'm trying to do this on the fly. Say, to dynamically make some references for every js file in a folder. Whatever. Anything. I'll run with it once I get a good starting point.

Comment: If you keep all your scripts in a folder I imagine you could write something to get all the file names, then inject them formatted as references in the .js files. I'm thinking a small console app or similiar. Actually, even if they aren't all in a folder you could hunt for every .js file, but that would be more of a pain

Comment: That works, Andrew, but is a little more involved than I'd like. Kind of hacky. But still appreciated and upvoted. Also wouldn't go over too well in a TFS environment.

Comment: If you figure something slick out let us know :-). I think you could write up a references generator app in a couple of hours. For the TFS concerns it would be just like any other code generation. You have to make sure and check out the files before running it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [T4](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) to read all the files in the current folder and below? (accounting for, if necessary scripts that are not actually included in the project but present in the file system).

Or even better and more likely related to what you are trying to do?

Use the nice centralized [_references.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319645/what-is-the-references-js-used-for) VS helper for scripts that are core in functionality to the others that you are editing.

Comment: I am modifying the _references.js file. You say "helper?" Does it do anything or do you have to manually update it, as I've been doing?

Comment: It is manually unless you make a `T4` generate that file. Although it is possible some `.js` nuget packages would look for that file and update it for you when you add them I suppose.