# JQuery VS DOC is added but intelligence is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a fresh project in MVC3. Jquery is already referenced in Layout view but vs-doc intellegence is not coming.

[image: JQuery Intelligence is not working]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174554/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-jquery-intellisense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try referencing jquery-1.5.1.js in Same file where you want intelligence.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


@if (false) 
{ 
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
}
```

In this way intelligence will work and js file will not be downloaded to client.

Comment: Yes but in this way, I have to reference in all files. I have already reference in Layout view